# Which layer should I use to factorize the existence checking of a ressource?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to factorize the fact that for all routes that are similar to : `/ressources/:id/*` we should always check the ressource existence.

I'm not sure how to do it the proper NestJS.

Should I use a middleware, a guard or even pipes (it can be seen as a kind of validation) ?

Hope my question is clear enough,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a pipe is a proper spot in this case, as a guard will return a 403 and a middleware runs the query to your database before you've authenticated the request. You can also use DI in the pipe to make the queries to the database easier, and use the pipe only on the body or request param, depending on how you want to handle things.